# What is different between int (%d) and %.0lf?

Tags: c++, printf, c++14

in C++

```
int a, b, c;
double k;

scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
k = (double)a*a/(b*b + c*c);
printf("%.0lf %0.lf %d", sqrt(b*b*k), sqrt(c*c*k), (int)sqrt(c*c*k);
```

For example, 
input : 52 9 16
output: 25 45 45

But, I think that those is different.
Actually, judge differently in online judge.

What's different?

```
    printf("%.0lf %0.lf %d", sqrt(b*b*k), sqrt(c*c*k), (int)sqrt(c*c*k);
```

In the above sentence, l, not 1.

Is it different depending on the compiler?

Comment: It is not different depending on the compiler. What should this be: `%.0lf`

Comment: But, in online Judge, I got the "WRONG" when i wrote the %.0lf ,
but I got the 'CORRECT" when i wrote the %d with (int)sqrt(bla);

Comment: I'm asking you again, what do you expect with `%.0lf`? What is this `0` there?

Comment: Integer, ex) If result is 2.3, I expected 2.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but are you really programming in C++? There's nothing specific to C++ in the code you show, it could all be plain standard C.

Comment: And do you mean `%0.lf` or `%.0lf`? Those two formats does different things.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ye, but cin and cout take a long time. So, I use the C++ and C, but Compiler is gcc c++ 14

Comment: `%.0lf` and `%0.lf` should both have the same effect as truncating the double to an int (leading flag `0` is ignored if you're not actually padding the output, and precision `.` defaults to zero if the argument is omitted)

Comment: %0.lf  , %.0lf  and %d (int casting) , Result is same.

Comment: @Useless What you mean is that %.0lf and %0.lf are the same. right?

Comment: They're not exactly the same, but they ought to give the same output.

Answer (score 1):

In `printf("%d", (int)sqrt(...))` the cast to integer truncates digits to integer, so 2.9 becomes 2 - and %d prints that.

But in `printf("%0.lf", sqrt(...))` the floating point number is rounded to zero decimal digits, so 2.9 is written as 3.

Thus if the answer isn't an integer the results might differ.

Comment: double db;

 db = 19 / 10;
 printf("%d %.0lf %0.lf", int(db), db, db);

but, result is 1 1 1

Comment: Try db=19.0 / 10.0;

Answer (score -1):

The two things

- `%d` means a **decimal (signed) integer**
- `%lf` means a <s>long float</s> now called **double** precision floating point number and

  - `%.0lf` means a double number with **zero digits after the decimal point** so it is fundamentally the same as an integer. There's a small difference, though, that when converting to `int` the digits after the decimal point are thrown away directly while when converting to `%.0lf`, it's rounded to the nearest integer.

So the expected output is exactly the same. I have no idea why you're expecting different outputs.

Comment: It's C/C++, float will not be automatically coerced to an integer when passed to `printf()`. Floats and integers have different bit representations. Your answer is not correct

Comment: @NiklasR But PRINTF will strip everything after the decm point!

Comment: I think Niklas is pointing out that you need to pass an `int` to the `%d` format, not a `double`. OP's code is actually doing that cast though, so the output ought to be the same.

Comment: tbh. I didnt see the cast to `int` in OP's question. If you do not cast it, printf will still truncate after the decimal point, but the value you see will be different.

Comment: i'm very confused